# Old photographies coloring

Tags: image-processing, matlab, color

There is already a succesful question [How did they color old black and white movies?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-did-they-color-old-black-and-white-movies) on this site. Very general and correspondingly in general answered. Let me please narrow it down to just the photograpy (i.e. no time dimension) and more specified starting point:

**What is the algorithm to color the greyscale HD picture given the colors at various points on greyscale original?**

**Note:** Yes, I am aware that the original colors can't be restored any more.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Doesn't that question and its answer tell you that already? `... by using vector masks to indicate regions of uniform color on a few keyframes, and interpolating between them. Then a color transform is applied to each mask.` And then the last paragraph on automating the process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have read that, but I was looking for more detailed answer, if it would be possible.

Comment: I'll leave the question open. Let's see what answers you get (or not).

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful to you: *Oscar Dalmau Cedeño, Mariano Rivera, Teresa Alarcón: [Bayesian Scheme for Interactive Colourization, Recolourization and Image/Video Editing](http://www.cimat.mx/~mrivera/journals/dalmau_color_cgf11.pdf). Comput. Graph. Forum 29(8): 2372-2386, 2010.  ISSN: 0167-7055*

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most important papers in this area:
[Colorization using Optimization](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/colorization-siggraph04.pdf).

You may found additional information with code [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~yweiss/Colorization/)